# A closed form for the antiderivative of $\frac 1{\sin^5 x +\cos^5 x} $

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

Does there exist a closed form expression for  $$\int \dfrac {dx}{\sin^5 x +\cos^5 x}? $$

Answer (score 8):

Given $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sin^5 x+\cos^5 x}dx$

First we will simplify $\sin^5 x+\cos^5 x = \left(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x\right)\cdot \left(\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x\right) - \sin ^2x\cdot \cos ^2x\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)$

$\displaystyle  \sin^5 x+\cos^5 x= (\sin x+\cos x)\cdot (1-\sin x\cdot \cos x-\cos^2 x\cdot \sin^2x)$

So Integral is $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sin^5 x+\cos^5 x}dx $

$\displaystyle = \int\frac{1}{(\sin x+\cos x)\cdot (1-\sin x\cdot \cos x-\cos^2 x\cdot \sin^2x)}dx$

$\displaystyle = \int \frac{(\sin x+\cos x)}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2\cdot (1-\sin x\cdot \cos x-\cos^2 x\cdot \sin^2x)}dx$

$\displaystyle  = \int \frac{(\sin x+\cos x)}{(1+\sin  2x)\cdot (1-\sin x\cdot \cos x-\cos^2 x\cdot \sin^2x)}dx$

Let $(\sin x-\cos x) = t\;,$ Then $(\cos +\sin x)dx = dt$ and $(1-\sin 2x) = t^2\Rightarrow (1+\sin 2x) = (2-t^2)$

So Integral Convert into $\displaystyle  = 4\int\frac{1}{(2-t^2)\cdot(5-t^4)}dt = 4\int\frac{1}{(t^2-2)\cdot (t^2-\sqrt{5})\cdot (t^2+\sqrt{5})}dt$

Now Using partial fraction, we get

$\displaystyle = 4\int \left[\frac{1}{2-t^2}+\frac{1}{(2-\sqrt{5})\cdot 2\sqrt{5}\cdot (\sqrt{5}-t^2)}+\frac{1}{(2+\sqrt{5})\cdot 2\sqrt{5}\cdot (\sqrt{5}+t^2)}\right]dt$

$ = \displaystyle \sqrt{2}\ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{2}+t}{\sqrt{2}-t}\right|+\frac{1}{(2-\sqrt{5})\cdot 5^{\frac{3}{4}}}\cdot \ln \left|\frac{5^{\frac{1}{4}}+t}{5^{\frac{1}{4}}-t}\right|+\frac{2}{(2+\sqrt{5})\cdot 5^{\frac{3}{4}}}\cdot \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{5^{\frac{1}{4}}}\right)+\mathbb{C}$

where $t=(\sin x-\cos x)$

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is.  Any rational expression in sine and cosine has an elementary antiderivative.  Use the substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$, follow your nose, and you should end up with a rational integrand of $t$.  Then partial fraction decomposition will take you home.  This general method will work for any rational expression of sines and cosines.  Ultimately, it works because it gives you a rational parameterization of the unit circle.

Comment: If the polynomial of the denominator has degree > 4 with roots not expressible by radicals...

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I suppose you are right. Depends on what you mean by "closed form".  I would admit any real number as allowable constants in my "closed form".  In this particular case, I think everything will be fine (although you may need to stray outside of the real numbers to have a nice expression.  I imagine 5th roots of unity will probably enter the picture.)

Comment: The usual definition of "elementary function" allows any algebraic function as a step.  (I mean the definition in serious textbooks, not necessarily the one(s) found on various web pages.)

Comment: Another comment.  The $\tan(x/2)$ substitution always works, although it can make computations much longer than other methods, if available.

Answer (score 1):

Computer algebra systems can do this.  Maybe this is not needed, since the question (answered by Steven) was only whether closed form exists (not to exhibit it).  But just for fun I gave it to Maple...

$$
1/5\,i\sqrt {\sqrt {5}+2}\ln  \left(  \left( \tan \left( 1/2\,x
 \right)  \right) ^{2}+ \left( 1/2\,i \left( \sqrt {5}+2 \right) ^{3/2
}+1/2+1/2\,\sqrt {5}-5/2\,i\sqrt {\sqrt {5}+2} \right) \tan \left( 1/2
\,x \right) -1/2\,i \left( \sqrt {5}+2 \right) ^{3/2}+1/2-1/2\,\sqrt {
5}+5/2\,i\sqrt {\sqrt {5}+2} \right) 
\\-1/5\,i\sqrt {\sqrt {5}+2}\ln 
 \left(  \left( \tan \left( 1/2\,x \right)  \right) ^{2}+ \left( -1/2
\,i \left( \sqrt {5}+2 \right) ^{3/2}+1/2+1/2\,\sqrt {5}+5/2\,i\sqrt {
\sqrt {5}+2} \right) \tan \left( 1/2\,x \right) +1/2\,i \left( \sqrt {
5}+2 \right) ^{3/2}+1/2-1/2\,\sqrt {5}-5/2\,i\sqrt {\sqrt {5}+2}
 \right) 
\\+1/5\,\sqrt {-2+\sqrt {5}}\ln  \left(  \left( \tan \left( 1/2
\,x \right)  \right) ^{2}+ \left( -1/2\, \left( -2+\sqrt {5} \right) ^
{3/2}+1/2-1/2\,\sqrt {5}-5/2\,\sqrt {-2+\sqrt {5}} \right) \tan
 \left( 1/2\,x \right) +1/2\, \left( -2+\sqrt {5} \right) ^{3/2}+1/2+1
/2\,\sqrt {5}+5/2\,\sqrt {-2+\sqrt {5}} \right) 
\\-1/5\,\sqrt {-2+\sqrt 
{5}}\ln  \left(  \left( \tan \left( 1/2\,x \right)  \right) ^{2}+
 \left( 1/2\, \left( -2+\sqrt {5} \right) ^{3/2}+1/2-1/2\,\sqrt {5}+5/
2\,\sqrt {-2+\sqrt {5}} \right) \tan \left( 1/2\,x \right) -1/2\,
 \left( -2+\sqrt {5} \right) ^{3/2}+1/2+1/2\,\sqrt {5}-5/2\,\sqrt {-2+
\sqrt {5}} \right) 
\\+4/5\,\sqrt {2}{\rm{ arctanh}} \left( 1/4\, \left( 2
\,\tan \left( 1/2\,x \right) -2 \right) \sqrt {2} \right) 
$$
In this case, we only had to solve two successive quadratic equations.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the identity
$$\sin^5 (t+\frac\pi4) +\cos^5(t+\frac\pi4)
=\sqrt2 \cos t\left(\frac{5}4-\cos^4 t\right)
$$
to integrate
\begin{align}
&\int \dfrac {1}{\sin^5 (t+\frac\pi4) +\cos^5(t+\frac\pi4)}dt\\
=& \frac{2\sqrt2}5 \int\bigg(\frac1{\cos^2 t}-\frac{1}{2\cos^2 t+\sqrt5}
-\frac{1}{2\cos^2 t-\sqrt5} \bigg)\cos t \>dt \\
=& \frac25\bigg(\sqrt2\tanh^{-1}\sin t
-\frac{\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt2\sin t}{\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}}
+\frac{\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt2 \sin t}{\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}}}{\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}}\bigg)+C
\end{align}
Then, replace $t=x-\frac\pi4$ to arrive at the original integral.
In particular
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac {dx}{\sin^5 x +\cos^5 x}
=\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4} \dfrac {1}{\sin^5 (t+\frac\pi4) +\cos^5(t+\frac\pi4)}dt
\\
=&\frac45\bigg( \sqrt2\coth^{-1}\sqrt2-\frac{\coth^{-1} \sqrt{\sqrt5+2}}{\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}}
+ \frac{\cot^{-1} \sqrt{\sqrt5-2}}{\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}}\bigg)
\end{align}